# deleting position:absolute magically makes text underlined

Tags: html, css

so I'm pretty new at HTML/CSS, and I'm trying to build a pretty basic homepage for myself that I could put on a business card. At the top of my page, I have a list of buttons (not bootstrap btw), and they are right now positioned absolutely.
 The problem is that in my effort to make my website more flexible for different screen sizes, I don't want them to be that way. 
However, deleting the position: absolute from their properties 
(in my testing I deleted it from .button1) 
causes an underline to magically appear.

Here's a gif of what happens when I delete the position:absolute:
https://gyazo.com/03e95bf02e822b544a39518b1923a7db

I will include my code here, but don't laugh at how awful I'm sure it is.

any help is good help!

HTML:

```
        <body>
        <h1 id="samsmith">Sam Smith</h1>

        <div id="buttonbox">
            <a href="https://www.smitty1ky.tumblr.com">    
                <h1 class="button1">
                    <div class="button1con">
                    Tumblr
                    </div>
                </h1>
            </a>

            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/smitty1ky">    
                <h1 class="button2">
                    <div class="button2con">
                    spotify
                    </div>
                </h1>
            </a>

           <a href="http://westwoodlitmag.com">    
                <h1 class="button3">
                    <div class="button3con">
                    WestWood
                    </div>
                </h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <p id="welcome"> Welcome.</p>
        <p id="student">Student at <a href="http://woodford.kyschools.us/">WCHS.</a></p>
        <p id="inprogress">Coming Soon</p>

        <h6 class="footer">&copy; Samuel T Smith 2015</h6>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
           body {
           background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/5oH1");
       }


        #samsmith {
            font-family:Megrim;
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size: 100px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }


        .button1con {
            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/VjUJ");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            height: 35px;
            width:100px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button1 {
            position: absolute;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:0;
            left:0;
        }

        .button1:hover .button1con {background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/IWM6") }
        .button1:hover {color:  rgb(0,0,0);   }

        .button2con {

            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/VjUJ");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            height: 35px;
            width:100px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button2 {
            position:absolute;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:250;
            left:0;
        }

        .button2:hover .button2con {background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/IWM6") }
        .button2:hover {color:  rgb(0,0,0);   }

        .button3con {

            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/088x");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            height: 35px;
            width:150px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button3 {
            position:absolute;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:0;
            left:250;
        }

        .button3:hover .button3con {background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/DZaI") }
        .button3:hover {color:  rgb(0,0,0);   }

        a:link       {
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
        }
        a:visited {
            color: rgb(236, 228, 217);
        }
        a:hover {
            color: rgb(0,0,0);
            background-color: rgb(236,228,217);
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a.buttons:link       {
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a.buttons:visited    {
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a.buttons:hover      {
            color: rgb(0,0,0);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a.button1:link {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        p {
            font-family:Megrim;
            color: rgb(236,228,217)
        }
        p#welcome {
            position: relative;
            top:300;
            font-size: 50px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }
        p#student {
            position: relative;
            top:300;
            font-size: 30px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #inprogress {
            font-size: 75px;
            position: relative;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            letter-spacing: 30px;
        }

        .footer {
            font-family: Megrim;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #282828;
            bottom: -45;
            right: 10;
        }

        @keyframes colors {
              0% {color: white;}
             50%  {color: red;}
            100%   {color: white;}
        }

        #inprogress {
            animation-name:colors;
            animation-duration:5s;
            animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        }

             @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {


           #samsmith {
            font-family:Megrim;
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size: 100px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

       }
             @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {


           #samsmith {
            font-family:Megrim;
            color: rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size: 75px;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .button3con {
            position:absolute;
            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/088x");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:0;
            height: 35px;
            width:150px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button3 {
            position:relative;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:0;
            left:-20;
            top:75px;
        }

        .button2con {
            position:absolute;
            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/VjUJ");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:40;
            height: 35px;
            width:100px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button2 {
            position:absolute;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:250;
            left:0;
        }

        .button1con {
            position:absolute;
            background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/VjUJ");
            margin:auto;
            right:0;
            left:80;
            height: 35px;
            width:100px;
            padding-top:5;
        }

        .button1 {
            position:absolute;
            font-family:Megrim;
            color:  rgb(236,228,217);
            font-size:25;
            padding-top:0;
            margin:auto;
            text-align:center;
            height:40px;
            width:100px;
            right:0;
            left:0;
        }

       }
```

edit 1: it's also worth mentioning that my id="buttonbox" has not been implemented at all aside from being given a name, so that is probably not the issue.

edit 2: created a jsfiddle but its super broken. unsure why, please advise http://jsfiddle.net/b8z9y9rr/

Comment: thats odd. it might have something to do with the fact that I dont have a style sheet seperate from my html doc then? I also am just realizing that I didnt include all of my css, so im going to edit and throw that in there

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the code you have included. Please expand your question to include enough code to be able to reproduce the problem. You can use a code snippet when you edit your post or add your code into a jsfiddle.net and provide a link.

Comment: making a jsfiddle now

Comment: okay put it all in jsfiddle and it is completely broken compared to my website. unsure how to proceed. http://jsfiddle.net/b8z9y9rr/
however, the issue is present on my website officialsamsmith.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All browsers' default anchor style has `text-decoration: underline`. All of your links are underlined and your question should state instead: **Why two of my links are not underlined?**

The answer is: [CSS text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) is not inherited by default and you nested a `div` with absolute position inside two of your anchors. [Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) takes content our of flow and therefor **it is not underlined**.

The solution is: Apply your styles directly to anchors, not to child elements.

Talking with HTML:

```css
.buttonbox {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
}
.buttonbox a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.button1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.button2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
}
.button3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Use this:</p>
<div class="buttonbox">
    <a class="button1" href="https://www.smitty1ky.tumblr.com">Tumblr</a>
    <a class="button2" href="https://open.spotify.com/user/smitty1ky">spotify</a>
    <a class="button3" href="http://westwoodlitmag.com">WestWood</a>
</div>
<p>NOT this:</p>
<div class="buttonbox">
    <a href="https://www.smitty1ky.tumblr.com"><div class="button1">Tumblr</div></a>
    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/smitty1ky"><div class="button2">spotify</div></a>
    <a href="http://westwoodlitmag.com"><div class="button3">WestWood</div></a>
</div>
```

Also on **[Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/e6vdhnuq/1/)**.

Comment: I think you solved all my problems. as soon as I can get it working Ill mark the solution

Comment: okay so not exactly a solution to my problem, but you did enable me (through some trials and tribulations) to solve the problem, so I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Glad it helped in any way.